# Adding Data Annotation Attribute Error to object error List

Tags: asp.net-mvc, data-annotations

I have the following code:

```
 public class WebSiteCloneEditModel
{               
    public WebSiteCloneEditModel()
    {
        FromWebsiteId = 0;
        Code = "";
        Name = "";
        Domain = "";
    }

    [Range(1, double.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Website is Required")]
    [Display(Name = "Choose website to clone:")]
    public int FromWebsiteId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Code")]
    public string Code { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Domain")]
    public string Domain { get; set; }

    public ErrorManagement ErrorLists
    {
        get { return UnitOfWork.Instance.GetLastError(); }
    }

}
```

and the following method in Controller :

```
 public JsonResult ExecuteClone(WebSiteCloneEditModel cloneModel)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //redirect to new website
            var result = WebsiteExtension.CloneWebSiteFrom(cloneModel);
            if (result > 0)
            {
                return Json(JsonResponse.Get(new { url = "/Admin/Websites/Edit/" + result }, message: "Success", responsecode: ResponseCode.Success, description: "Clone is created"));

            }
            else
            {
                return Json(JsonResponse.Get(new { url = "/Admin/Websites" }, message: "Error", responsecode: ResponseCode.Success, description: "Clone is faild"));
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return Json(JsonResponse.Get(message: "Error", responsecode: ResponseCode.Error, response: cloneModel.ErrorLists));
        }
    }
```

For the case when ModelState is not Valid I send object Error List in Json.
How to Ad that error from Range Attribute in model to his Error list ?
I suppose this could be done somehow inside the model.

Please,advice!

Comment: The following will create a list of all the properties that have errors `var errors = ModelState.Keys.Where(k => ModelState[k].Errors.Count > 0).Select(k => new { propertyName = k, errorMessage = ModelState[k].Errors[0].ErrorMessage });`

Answer (score 0):

I had to do something similar recently and ended up using an extension method to get the errors. I found it on stack overflow but don't have the url to the original to attribute the work to.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the ModelState errors as an IEnumerable of strings.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="modelState">The ModelState dictionary.</param>
    /// <returns>
    /// Returns the ModelState errors as an IEnumerable of strings.
    /// </returns>
    public static IEnumerable<string> GetModelStateErrors(this System.Web.Mvc.ModelStateDictionary modelState)
    {
        List<string> msgList = new List<string>();
        foreach (var ms in modelState.Values)
        {
            foreach (var modelError in ms.Errors)
            {
                msgList.Add(modelError.ErrorMessage);
            }
        }
        return msgList;
    }
```

Use like this.

```
var modelErrors = ModelState.GetModelStateErrors();
```

You can then build your ErrorManagement object based on the strings returned.